# Identify rows in Pandas dataframe that already exist

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes; let's call one `old_df` and the other `new_df`. I want to highlight the rows in `new_df` that are not present in `old_df`. So for example:

```
import pandas as pd

old_df = pd.DataFrame({'m':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'n':['a','b','c','d','e','f']})

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'m':[2,5,7,8],
                       'n':['b','e','g','h']})
```

These dataframes look like:

```
   m  n
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  4  d
4  5  e
5  6  f
```

and

```
   m  n
0  2  b
1  5  e
2  7  g
3  8  h
```

I want to produce a mask for `new_df` that indicates whether the row already exists in `old_df`, something like:

```
0    True
1    True
2    False
3    False
```

I have been able to concatenate the columns as strings into a single string values to produce two Pandas Series and then use `.isin()` on the two series as follows:

```
msk = pd.Series(new_df['m'].astype(str) + new_df['n']).isin(pd.Series(old_df['m'].astype(str) + old_df['n']))

print(msk)
```

to produce:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

This is the correct outcome but is much too ugly to be the best answer. I thought `.isin()` might also work on dataframes but I couldn't get that to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have duplicated data in the new dataframe, you can concatenate them and check for duplicates:

```
(pd.concat([d.assign(is_old=n) for d,n in zip((old_df,new_df), ('old','new'))])
   .assign(from_old=lambda x: x.duplicated(['m','n']))
   .query('is_old=="new"')
)
```

Output:

```
   m  n is_old  from_old
0  2  b    new      True
1  5  e    new      True
2  7  g    new     False
3  8  h    new     False
```

Or you could use `merge` with `indicator=True`:

```
(old_df.merge(new_df, on=['m','n'], how='right', indicator=True)
      .assign(from_old=lambda x: x['_merge']=='both')
)
```

Output:

```
   m  n      _merge  from_old
0  2  b        both      True
1  5  e        both      True
2  7  g  right_only     False
3  8  h  right_only     False
```

Comment: There have been a lot of good answers submitted but, for me, the most intuitive was the suggestion to use merge with indicator=True option and then look for 'both' in the '_merge' column. I hadn't thought of merging two dataframes based on all the columns that exist in both. I've marked as accepted answer for the second of your two suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `merge` and compare the `index`:

```
new_df["status"] = new_df.index.isin(new_df.merge(old_df,on=["m","n"]).index)

print (new_df)

   m  n  status
0  2  b    True
1  5  e    True
2  7  g   False
3  8  h   False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
mask = []
for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    mask.append((old_df == np.array(row)).all(1).any())
print(mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `set`

Create a `set` and check containment

```
s = set(zip(*map(old_df.get, new_df)))
mask = [t in s for t in zip(*map(new_df.get, new_df))]
new_df.assign(status=mask)

   m  n  status
0  2  b    True
1  5  e    True
2  7  g   False
3  8  h   False
```

---

#### Some Details

`s` is the set of all rows from `old_df` in the form of tuples.  We take care to ensure the order of items in those tuples are the same as the order of those items from `new_df`

```
print(s)

{(5, 'e'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (6, 'f'), (1, 'a')}
```

The `mask` is a list comprehension that checks each row (as a tuple) in `new_df` and sees if it is present in our set `s`

```
print(mask)

[True, True, False, False]
```